# How can I dynamically generate Html content with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server

I understand how I can serve Html pages through Node.js to a client. Now I'm looking for a way to programatically generate Html on the server side (and then do whatever I want with it: save to a file, send to a client). Similiar to the way you'd do the same on the client side, with methods such as `document.createElement` or jQuery.

How can programatic Html generation be done with Node.js? (And I don't mean hardcoded Html writing to a file, of course).

Answer (score -3):

I think for your purpose reactjs might be the library to look at. It creates a virtual DOM node which is stateful and changes only on statechanges.

for serverside rendering this might be perfect for you! ;)