# How can I programatically generate Html on the server, without a third party library?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server

I asked a similar question, but before it got closed as a duplicate I forgot to mention I want to understand how to do this without using a third party library.

[How can I dynamically generate Html content with Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023829/how-can-i-dynamically-generate-html-content-with-node-js)

So, how can I programatically generate Html content on the server side using Node.js? (I don't mean sending hard-coded Html, I mean generating it like you would on the client side).

(I have nothing against 3rd party libraries. I prefer to understand Node.js well before learning about libraries on top of it).

Comment: Just concatenate string and return them as a response

Comment: What is it that you don't like about 3rd party libraries?

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: You'll either need to use a templating library, or you'll need to write one yourself. These libraries need to parse plain text templates, usually using a series of regular expressions to discover and replace certain special strings with other variables. Then create regular HTML from that parsed content.

Comment: There is no shame in using a library or framework that does things that are more complicated than you understand, especially while learning. Attempting to learn how templating works under the hood without knowing the rest of javascript will likely leave you with more questions than answers.

Answer (score 0):

```javascript
var http = require('http');
var html = '<!doctype html><html><body><h1>Hello, World!</h1></body></html>';

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(html);
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your webserver listening on whatever port you want, then have it respond to requests to whatever endpoint you want with whatever html you want.

```
// Include the HTTP Node library
// http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html
var http = require('http');

// define the IP and port number
var localIP = "127.0.0.1"; // 127.0.0.1 is used when running the server locally
var port = 8080; // port to run webserver on

function sayHello(req, res) {

    console.log("We've got a request for " + req.url);

    // HTTP response header - the content will be HTML MIME type
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

    // Write out the HTTP response body
    res.write('<html><body>' +
    '<h1>Hello Dynamic World Wide Web<h1>'+
    '</body></html>');

    // End of HTTP response
    res.end();

}

/************************/
/*  START THE SERVER    */
/************************/

// Create the HTTP server
var server = http.createServer(sayHello);

// Turn server on - now listening for requests on localIP and port
server.listen(port, localIP);

// print message to terminal that server is running
console.log('Server running at http://'+ localIP +':'+ port +'/');
```

the above code was taken from https://gist.github.com/johnschimmel/1759465

Comment: Thanks but this isn't what I meant. I meant to ask if there's a way to generate the page programatically, like the way you'd use e.g. `document.createElement` and such on the client side. Is there a way to do something like that using pure Node?

Comment: Probably, but that's not how you normally generate html in node. The DOM api isn't part of javascript, and therefore isn't available in node unless you include a 3rd party library.

Comment: I see. I assumed Node had it's own DOM Api. I'll look into a 3rd party library. Thanks

Comment: It would be interesting if a 3rd party library could pull off allowing you to generate a full document with included events, that then outputs cross-browser javascript/html to bind said events/logic on the browser. Though, i doubt anyone has put enough time into such a solution since it's uses are relatively small, considering how popular backbone/angular/templates and the like are now days.

Comment: What you have to keep in mind is that the server can only return plain text to the browser, either in the form of html, javascript, or a data format such as json or xml for the javascript to consume. Generating a document serverside serves no purpose if it doesn't get converted to an html string before being sent to the browser. doing so is usually only done for unit testing.